# After upgrade, Apache does not load changed httpd.conf on restart, I need to restart computer

Tags: macos, apache

I have a strange problem on my mac after upgrading to latest Mac OS Sierra . Whenever I edit **httpd.conf** in the path **/etc/apache2/** and restart apache using command

```
# sudo apachectl restart
```

The changes do not take effect. I have to restart computer for changes to take effect. I have googled with no luck.

Things were working perfect for years. Has something changed in apache 2.4 ? May be it is caching config file...?

My OS version is

```
Mac OS Sierra 10.12.6 (16G29)
```

My Apache version is

```
Apache/2.4.25 (Unix)
```

Please help

**Edited:**
I think it is due to the fact that even after stopping apache, some instances are still running.

```
# sudo apachectl stop
httpd (no pid file) not running

# ps au | grep apache
username   700   0.0  0.0  2432804    772 s001  S+    1:17pm   0:00.00 grep apache
```

I can then kill this instance and any other instance using the following command

```
# kill -9 <process id>
```

I tried but does not seem to work. Process ID just keeps changing.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
alias apache_start='sudo httpd -k start; sudo apachectl start;';
alias apache_stop='sudo apachectl stop; sudo httpd -k stop;';
```